# Get memory usage of this process C++ Win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, ram

Please point me to the easiest way to find out how much RAM current process is used.

Platform: Windows 10
Language: С++
Library: Win API

1. I know about HeapWalk/HeapSize but may be something more simple exists?
2. Calling the external process (wmi or tasklist) is very slow.

Comment: [Working set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/working-set).

Comment: This is a problematic question. What do you want to include? Windows can assign and unassign RAM at any time, meaning that any answer is instantly out of date. Your available virtual address space is typically much larger than physical RAM, precisely because Windows doesn't need to back it. Some of the RAM used by your process, mapped into your virtual address , is not exclusively mapped (especially with DLL's). And then there are file caches and other OS-internal structures that logically belong to your process, even if they're not mapped in.

Comment: @MSalters Any article or book suggestions i.e. [Windows via C/C++ (softcover) Fifth Edition
by Jeffrey Richter, Christophe Nasarre](https://www.amazon.com/Windows-via-softcover-Developer-Reference/dp/0735663777)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With win [API GetProcessMemoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo) you can obtain a process memory information,for example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    ::PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
    if ( ::GetProcessMemoryInfo( ::GetCurrentProcess(), &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) ) {
        std::cout << "Current process working set size " << (pmc.WorkingSetSize / 1024) << " KiB" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Current process peak working set size " << (pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize / 1024) << " KiB" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As well as you can profile your app without adding any additional code [profiling with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022)

And with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) you can obtains any system process detailed information.